# the first start with PHPUnit

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit

I just installed Eclipse Oxygen
Then I installed PHP 7.0.22

In Eclipse I create a PHP project "phput"
Then following the guide found in 
https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html

In the project folder

> $ composer.phar require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6

Everything seems OK

> ```
> $ cat composer.json 
> {
> "require-dev": {
> "phpunit/phpunit": "^6"
> }
> ```
>
> }
>   $ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --version 
>   PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

However, when I look at my project in Eclipse, most of the components in vendor have some sort of errors (71 errors in total)

[this is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK1EK.png)

Even the class `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` causes this error `...cannot resolved to a type`

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the vendor folder from your project source folders by marking it as a library folder,

> right-click » Use as Library Folder

that way Eclipse will still read it for code completion and to show you documentation but it won't show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable composer support for you project: right click on project -> configure -> add composer support
2. Update project build path: right click on project -> composer -> update build path
3. Wait a moment

*Note: Since PHPUnit 6, PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase become PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase*

*Note 2 Current stable PDT version (5.2) doesn't work well with PHPUnit 6. This was fixed in PDT 5.3: https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/NewIn53 now available via nightly builds, see https://eclipse.org/pdt/ for links.*